# react-router browserHistory.push doesn't navigate to new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried to follow the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526825/browserhistory-push-doesnt-navigate-to-new-page) and in the [react-router example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating) but I'm still having trouble.

I'm using react-router version 2.4.1, React version 15.1.0, and webpack 1.13.1.

I have a router that is set up like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Component from './component';
import Merchant from './merchant';
import CreateMerchant from './create-merchant';
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
// /* globals document, window */
//
// const { pathname, search, hash } = window.location
// const location = `${pathname}${search}${hash}`

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Component}/>
        <Route path="/merchant" component={CreateMerchant}/>
        <Route path="/merchant/:merchantId" component={Merchant}/>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"))
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/ I see the component as expected:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit(event) {
        const merchantId = event.target.elements[1].value;

        console.log("Merchant id is " + merchantId);

        const path = `/#/merchant/${merchantId}`;

        browserHistory.push(path);
    }


    render() {
        return <div className="container">
            <h1>Welcome to VPager!</h1>
            <h2>Would you like to create a merchant?</h2>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/merchant">Yes, create a merchant and start taking
                        customers.</Link>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h2>Or do you have an existing merchant?</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">I have an
                            existing merchant ID, and it is:</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-2"><input id="merchantId" className="form-control" type="number" /></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    }
}
```

When I click the second button, though, the URL in the address bar changes, but the new view is not rendered.

It seems that people had [similar issues in the past](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3062), but those solutions aren't working either.

I also tried [creating a higher order component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) and nesting the routes with a top-level component.  In that case, however, I get the error that "The root route must render exactly one element."

How do I get the form to navigate to a new view?

Comment: Is the page refreshing? Are you just missing `event.preventDefault()` in your  submit handling function?

Comment: There's no page refresh and no `event.preventDefault()`.  Even with that call, it still does the same thing.

Comment: Oh.. I just  noticed you have a `#` in your `path`, but you're not using `hashHistory`. It should probably be `const path = ``/merchant/${merchantId}``

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty dumb of me.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an errant `#` in your `path` variable, possibly left over from using `hashHistory`. Leave it out, should work:

```
const path = `/merchant/${merchantId}`
```