# React Router: browserHistory.push() not working proplerly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a function *checkAuth* which I want to trigger before entering '/home'. I am using react-router 2.6.0

My code (relevant part) looks like this -

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory, IndexRedirect} from 'react-router';
import Layout  from './Layout.jsx';
import HomePage from './HomePage.jsx';
import AuthPage from './AuthPage.jsx';

function checkAuth(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('auth')!='true'){
        console.log('inside'); // this is getting called
        browserHistory.push("/auth");
    }

}

const routes=(
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/home" />
        <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} onEnter={checkAuth} />
        <Route path="/auth" component={AuthPage} />
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Now the problem is that it is printing 'inside' in console and url changes from '/home' to '/auth' but inside Layout, I get **Home** component instead of **Auth** (desired in the current situation) component.

My Layout component  -

```
import React from 'react';

class Layout extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div id="container">{this.props.children}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Layout;
```

I also tried `browserHistory.replace('/auth')` but that also did not help me.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526825/browserhistory-push-doesnt-navigate-to-new-page) which suggested that layout component might not be able to render **Auth** component after **Home** component has rendered.

But I need some more insights on this problem. Also any approach to the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't your app missing a Router component? Something like   `<Router history={browserHistory}>` ?

Comment: @Axnyff That part is in a separate file. Here I showed only relevant code.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/35565731/4949918

Comment: I have read that link before. I also mentioned in my question that it says my component won't render, but why? Also is this the only way to do that?